# Datos de precipitación concatenados de CSV en columnas según fecha

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con varios archivos de precipitación en CSV. Concatene, pero no he podido agruparlos por estación (columna) en función del tiempo.
[![.][1]][1]

```
import pandas as pd

archivo = ['Estacion1.csv', 'Estacion2.csv', 'Estacion3.csv','Estacion4.csv','Estacion5.csv','Estacion6.csv','Estacion7.csv']

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(i) for i in archivo))
df

NombreEstacion  Fecha   Valor
0   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-15  4.5
1   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-16  18.0
2   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-17  8.6
3   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-18  18.0
4   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-19  4.0
... ... ... ...
15719   DOMINGODO [11100020]    2022-02-25  0.0
15720   DOMINGODO [11100020]    2022-02-26  0.0
15721   DOMINGODO [11100020]    2022-02-27  0.0
```

Dataframe esperado

```
Fecha   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  DOMINGODO [11100020]
0   2009-06-15  4.5     xx.x
1   2009-06-16  18.0    xx.x
2   2009-06-17  8.6     xx.x
3   2009-06-18  18.0    xx.x
4   2009-06-19  4.0     xx.x
```

Como puedo presentar las estaciones por columna. Gracias

Comment: Buen día, por favor incluye un ejemplo de tu `dataframe` como texto (No como imagen) y un ejemplo de cómo esperas los datos a la salida. También limita tu publicación a una sola pregunta ya que eso permite a otros usuarios encontrar la respuesta a preguntas similares.

Comment: Creo que has intentado poner la información en los comentarios porque me llegaron 5-6 notificaciones. Pulsa “editar” y agrégala en tu pregunta para que se vea claramente. Saludos

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato no había podido añadir, gracias por la guía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes lograrlo si agrupas por fechas con [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) y como segundo índice el `NombreEstacion`

Luego puedes agregar una columna y copiar los valores con [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) y `lambda`

Por último utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) para reducir a un solo índice (Ya que con groupby teníamos 2 índices: Fecha y NombreEstación)

El `dataframe` (sample2.csv) que estoy utilizando como ejemplo es (Inventé la primera fila para "DOMINGODO" para poder visualizar que sí se agrupa por fechas):

```
    NombreEstacion          Fecha       Valor
0   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-15  4.5
1   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-16  18.0
2   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-17  8.6
3   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-18  18.0
4   VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  2009-06-19  4.0
5   DOMINGODO [11100020]    2009-06-15  9.0
6   DOMINGODO [11100020]    2022-02-25  0.0
7   DOMINGODO [11100020]    2022-02-26  0.0
8   DOMINGODO [11100020]    2022-02-27  0.0
```

Aplicando los comentarios anteriores:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df1 = df.groupby(['Fecha', 'NombreEstacion']).agg({'Valor': lambda x: x}).unstack()
```

Al imprimir `df1` tenemos:

```
                                                         Valor
NombreEstacion  DOMINGODO [11100020]    VILLARTEAGA [12015010]
Fecha       
2009-06-15      9.0                     4.5
2009-06-16      NaN                     18.0
2009-06-17      NaN                     8.6
2009-06-18      NaN                     18.0
2009-06-19      NaN                     4.0
2022-02-25      0.0                     NaN
2022-02-26      0.0                     NaN
2022-02-27      0.0                     NaN
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @HeytalePazguato, me funcionó.

Comment: @faquimbayal, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.